# Activate absent from virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to launch a virtual environment to download a library : cv with `workon cv` following [a tutorial on image to text recognition](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/). Yet, when it was created it seemed weird :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful/extractText$ python -m virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/home/mike/anaconda3'
New python executable in /home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin/python
/home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: The executable /home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText' (should be '/home/mike/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I can't activate anything from it after creating it because I lack this `activate` thing to do the `source env/bin/activate` :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful/extractText/env/bin$ ls
python  python3  python3.6
```

Here is my python version. It looks weird :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful/extractText$ python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Comment: The Python version your venv is based on is broken. Did you do any changes on the installed Python versionsm

Comment: @KlausD. Yes : `Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`. What should I do ?